# Displaying double digits array elements

Tags: javascript, html, list, numbers

I want to make a program in javascript that when you enter 10 numbers, it appears in a list whose of them are even and whose not. But when displaying a double digit number, it appears like there are two elements instead of one.

```
<html>

    <head>

        <script language="Javascript">
          document.write("<h1>Numbers List</h1><ol><li>Evens</li><ul>");
          var i=0,evens=[],odds=[],number;
          while(i<10){
            number=parseInt(prompt())
            if(number%2==0){
              evens+=[number];
            } 

            else{
              odds+=[number];
            }
            i=i+1;
          }
         //Here the numbers are separated between evens and odds 

          i=0;
          while(i<evens.length){
            document.write("<li>"+evens[i]+"</li>");
            i=i+1;
          }
          i=0;
          document.write("</ul><li>Odds</li><ul>")
          while(i<odds.length){
            document.write("<li>"+odds[i]+"</li>");
            i=i+1;
          }
          
          document.write("</ul></ol>The total number of even numbers read has been: "+evens.length+"<br>");
          document.write("The total number of even numbers read has been: "+odds.length);
          
       </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    </body>

</html>
```

When I put

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

The result is

```
Numbers List
Evens
2
4
6
8
1
0
//The 0 and 1 needed to be a 10
Odds
1
3
5
7
9
The total number of even numbers read has been: 6
The total number of even numbers read has been: 5
```

I have searched in google but I haven't find a solution.

Comment: Try to change `evens+=[number]` to `evens.push(number)` (and the same for `odds`).

Comment: `evens += [number]` doesn't do what you think it does. You probably want `evens.push(number)` instead. You should get into the habit of checking your output in your dev tools to debug your code.

Comment: I knew that it didn't do what I wanted, but I didn't know what to put instead. Thanks for your answers. I'm new at programming.